# Could you simplify the highlighted parts

Tags: sentence-meaning

> To achieve PTCB Certification, candidates must satisfy the following eligibility requirements:
>
> *High school diploma or equivalent educational diploma (e.g., a GED or foreign diploma).
>
> - Full disclosure of all criminal and State Board of Pharmacy registration or **licensure actions** .
> - **Compliance with all applicable PTCB Certification policies** .
> - Passing score on the Pharmacy Technician Certification Exam (PTCE).
>
> A candidate may be disqualified for PTCB Certification upon the disclosure or discovery of:
>
> - **Criminal conduct** involving the candidate;
> - **State Board of Pharmacy registration or licensure action involving the candidate;**
> - Violation of a PTCB Certification policy, including but not limited to the **Code of Conduct** .
>
> PTCB reserves the right to investigate criminal background, verify candidate eligibility and deny certification to any individual.

Although I got the gist of the text, but it is still difficult to get the idea of what the highlighted part are about, let alone googleing the concept I do not understand.
I am sure that if you simplify the parts, it will certainley cast a light on the concept of the text and would help me to understand my following research conception.
I wonder when it says Pharmacy registration or **licensure actions** , does it talk about a resume ?
A million thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

- 'Licensure actions' refers to any action taken by the relevant board that may have affected your license to practice.
- evidently the PTCB has a written policy document containing standards you need to comply with
- criminal conduct refers to any record of criminal activities you have been charged or convicted with in the past
- see first point
- a Code of Conduct is a written document outlining how members of an organisation are expected to behave, in general and in given situations.

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand upon user8543's excellent answer, and further simplify:

If you are the candidate, you must:

- (Have a high school diploma or the equivalent.)
- Tell the PCTB about any crimes you've been convicted of or charged with; and, if you've ever been registered with or licensed by a State Board of Pharmacy, tell the PCTB about any limitation or revocation of that registration or license because of something you did.
- The PTCB Certification policies list any other things you might have to do to get certified.
- (And you have to pass the test.)

You might not get certified if you:

- Have committed crimes in the past.
- Have been registered with or licensed by a State Board of Pharmacy, and that registration or license was limited or revoked    because of something you did.
- Have done something not allowed under the PTCB Certification policy, which includes a Code of Conduct you are expected to follow. Most Codes of Conduct call for one to behave legally, ethically, and honestly, along with other more specific things (for example, the Code of Conduct probably says that you can't cheat on the Certificaton Exam).

The "registration and licensure action" stuff has nothing to do with resumes & so forth. It's about keeping someone who was certified in one state but did something to make himself lose that certification (like embezzling, or selling narcotics illegally) from just moving to another state and getting a new certification there.